# Como setar hostname em publicação asp net core 3.1 selfHosted

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp, iis

Tenho um projeto funcionando o qual a preferencia de publicação é no formato de publicar para pasta auto hospedado (selfhosted) (sem usar o IIS). Motivo de ser assim: o objetivo é diminuir o trabalho/conhecimento de quem vai implantar, não precisando configurar nada a não ser copiar, colar e executar o .exe. Nesse formato, a publicação gera numa pasta publish todos os arquivos necessários e um .exe, que ao executar levanta o serviço. conforme a imagem a seguir:

[image: Funcionamento esperado]

Obs.: No mesmo servidor tem o IIS hospedando outros dois sites feitos com asp .net framework, inclusive já utilizando a porta 80 em ambos, porém cada um com seu hostname diferente. exemplo: um é demo.nossosite.com.br on *:80 e o outro é dev.nossosite.com.br on *:80.

Importante ressaltar que para o funcionamento do novo site (feito em asp .net core selfhosted) conforme a imagem anterior, só foi possível após parar os dois sites que utilizavam a porta 80.
Com os dois sites funcionando na tentativa de levantar o novo, ocorre um erro conforme imagem:
[image: Erro]

"crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
Unable to start Kestrel.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10013): Foi feita uma tentativa de acesso a
um soquete de uma maneira que é proibida pelas permissões de acesso."

No IIS, na lista de Sites, botão direito sobre qualquer site, opção "Associações", é possível fazer a configuração de qual hostname juntamente com a porta apontara para aquele determinado site selecionado.

Creio que o problema que estou enfrentando esta relacionado a essa ausência de configuração de hostname.
Meios que já tentei:

- Em launchSettings.json attributo applicationUrl onde tinham citações de localhost troquei por sitenovo.nossosite.com.br
- Em appsettings.json attributo AllowedHosts onde tinha apenas um "*" troquei por "sitenovo.nossosite.com.br"
- Em Program.cs no metodo CreateHostBuilder usando .UseUrls() informando as urls correspondentes.

Parece que nenhum surte o mesmo efeito como seria a configuração de Associações feita no IIS citada anteriormente.
Antes que me indiquem: é só alterar a porta para outra porta diferente, para nosso cenário fica inviável, precisamos que seja na porta 80.
Alguém sabe como resolver isso/já passou por esse problema de precisar manter sites hospedados em IIS e ao mesmo tempo auto hospedados?

Comment: Você tem certeza que as duas aplicações não estavam com rotas diferentes? Por exemplo, "http://dev.nossosite.com.br:80/app1/xxxx" e "http://dev.nossosite.com.br:80/app2/xxxx"?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode até fazer o *binding* de um *dns host name* para a sua aplicação, assim por exemplo:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseUrls("http://dev.nossosite.com.br:80", "http://localhost:80")
```

Porém, não vai conseguir por mais de uma aplicação na mesma porta, na mesma máquina.

Isso é possível no `IIS` porque ele gerencia as requisições e faz os redirecionamentos corretos, já uma aplicação *self hosted* não é capas de fazer isso, porque, se tem duas app querendo fazer *bind* da mesma porta, quem vai gerenciar isso?

Tem que ser "alguém" além das duas (ou mais) apps para fazer isso, ai que entra o `IIS` ou outro servidor Web.